# Facebook cutting out special chars from XMLHttpRequest image share description which contains polish symbols

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, xmlhttprequest

Okay, so here's my problem.
I have the code which shares image directly to facebook via open graph. Even though it should send description with polish symbols without any problem it's not.

What I send as a description is this:
**Zdjęcie z aplikacji http://www.xxx.pl/**

What comes out on my wall as a description to the image is this: 
**Zdjcie z aplikacji http://www.xxx.pl/**

I've spent few hours on a research why is it happening and found pretty much nothing. I'd be really grateful for any idea about it as I'm really fed up with that crap.

That's part of my code responsible for posting data to facebook:

```js
function PostImageToFacebook(authToken, filename, mimeType, imageData, message) {

  var boundary = '----ThisIsTheBoundary1234567890';

  var formData = '--' + boundary + '\r\n'
  formData += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="source"; filename="' + filename + '"\r\n';
  formData += 'Content-Type: ' + mimeType + '\r\n\r\n';
  for (var i = 0; i < imageData.length; ++i) {
    formData += String.fromCharCode(imageData[i] & 0xff);
  }
  formData += '\r\n';
  formData += '--' + boundary + '\r\n';
  formData += 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="caption"\r\n';
  formData += 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n';
  formData += message + '\r\n'
  formData += '--' + boundary + '--\r\n';

  console.log(formData);

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('POST', 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos?access_token=' + authToken, true);
  xhr.onload = xhr.onerror = function() {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
    $(".photo-uploaded").fadeIn();
    $(".share_to_facebook").removeClass("disabled");
  };
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary + "; charset=utf-8");
  xhr.sendAsBinary(formData);
}

PostImageToFacebook(fbToken, imgDesc, "image/png", decodedPng, "Zdjęcie z aplikacji http://www.xxx.pl");
```

Comment: You are aware that the user has to type in the description of the photo, and that your app is not allowed to specify it for them, right?

Comment: I know - the text which is written in the method call is just for example purposes. I wanted to keep code in the example short and readable.

Even with that in mind - my app has passed facebook review even though I've disclosed that I might use static text for description. So I guess that's not really an issue for them.

Comment: Is your script properly encoded as/saved as/interpreted as UTF-8?

Comment: Yeah, It is. It's saved as UTF-8 file.

Comment: So does the same thing happen when you upload a photo on facebook.com manually, and use those characters in the image description? And what about when you make your request via Graph API Explorer (file upload is not so easy in there, but you can upload in image from an HTTP URL instead to test), does it mangle up the characters then, too?

Comment: That's exactly the case. No, it doesn't. It's only screwed up when I upload it directly via form-way. 
But as I have to upload it in the front-end layer there's no other way.

Comment: Well then likely something is wrong with your handling of the character encoding. Btw., instead of assembling the whole POST upload data yourself (which is rather error-prone), you should use [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) to begin with.

Comment: I have no idea what was wrong. Really. Encoding was right in files, in my form, and in few more places and it was still sending mashed up characters. I couldn't have used FormData in the beggining as IE9 didn't support it, but in the end we've dropped IE9 support, so thanks very much for that! I would've voted up your answer, but as it's the comment I just can't really do that :(